How can you find the total number of events a contact attended?
I want to generate a report that sorts our contacts by the number of events they have attended /  registered for. Is there a way to do that using search kit?
Can you do the same for other variables?
Thanks!
Name        # of Events Registered
Doe, John     9
Mark, James   7
Jenna, Lady   3
Smark, Sjshd  8
Mama, Baba    5


I think i figured it out.

Search for Contacts (with required)
Choose Contact Participants
Group by fx Contact ID

Make sure Contact ID, Sort Name, Event ID are columns.

Click Search to check your work

Go to Select Fields, Change Event ID from fx to Count

Click search and save.


You can also add event title as a column and it will list out every event they have attended. (unfortunately the events are not clickable) You might have to change the fx to list in Select Fields and you can order my Unique Record (which is event id) or alphabetical order (Distinct Value)

I would start with Participants as the base entity for the search and Group By Contact ID. That should give you what you need.

This also works, but you still need a count. thanks!
